# String cannot start with zero

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a string which i want to check with a regex. It is not allowed for it to start with a 0. So please see  the following examples:

```
012344 = invalid
3435545645 = valid
021 = invalid
344545 = valid
```

etc.

How does this regex look in PHP?

PS. This must be a regex solution!

Comment: Learning material: http://regular-expressions.info, http://rubular.com

Comment: This is not even valid PHP...

Comment: @KingCrunch I'm just showing the numbers that are valid or invalid. I never said it was PHP. I'm just looking for a solution **IN** PHP...

Comment: @KingCrunch Did he say anywhere that it was, or are you assuming that because it is within code section that it must be valid code rather than pseudo code?

Comment: @JonTaylor The tag sais. However, he wrote for example `012344 = invalid`, that is of course not a string, because it is not PHP. Even if you only take `012344` (compare with `"012344"`) is just a number and not a string. I thing its important to give reliable examples...

Comment: @KingCrunch thats absolutley ridiculous, he has PHP in the tag since he would like to know how to do this in PHP.  The example is perfectly clear, it states that 012344 is invalid, 3435545645 is valid etc, how is this in any way unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REGEX should looks like that :

```
^[1-9][0-9]*$
```

PHP Code :

```
<?php

    $regex = "#^[1-9][0-9]*$#";


    function test($value, $regex)
    {
          $text = "invalid";
          if(preg_match($regex, $value)) $text = "valid";
          return $value+" = "+$text+"\n\r";
    }

   echo  test('012345', $regex);
   echo  test('12345', $regex);

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Well it would be a simple `/[1-9][0-9]*/`.
Please research your question better next time.
This could have also helped you: [Regular expression tester](http://rubular.com/)

**Edit:**

Yeah, the answer got downvoted, because it's missing the anchors and seems to be wrong. For completess' sake, I posted the php code I would use with this regex. And no it's not wrong. It may not be the most elegant way, but I like checking whether the regex matched the whole string afterwards more. One reason is that to debug a regex and see what it actually matched I just have to comment out `=== $value` after `return $matches[0]`

```
<?php
  function matches($value) {
    preg_match("/[1-9][0-9]*/", $value, $matches);
    return $matches[0] === $value;
  }

  //Usage:
  if (matches("1234")) {
     //...
  }
?>
```

Comment: Well, obviously it's not that simple. You forgot the anchors which are essential for this to work.

Comment: It is only simple for those that know how.  I like to think myself as a proficient programmer, however I am the first to admit that Regex completely confuses me, yet I can competantly program a complex distributed multi agent system (to me this is easy, but could be very complex for others).